# Problem in passing parameters in a basic CRUD in Django from Views to index.html

Tags: python, mysql, django, crud

When I try to access the button named E the following error page is loaded
[image]

**views.py**

> ```
> def editar(request,id):
> cliente = Cliente.objects.get(id=id)
> formulario = ClienteForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=cliente)
> if formulario.is_valid and request.method == 'POST':
>     formulario.save()
>     return redirect('clientes')
> return render(request, 'clientes/editar.html',{'formulario':formulario})
> ```

**index.html**

```html
<td>
   <a name="" id="" class="btn btn-info" href="{% url 'editar' cliente.id %}" role="button">E</a>
</td>
<td>
   <a name="" id="" class="btn btn-danger" href=" {% url 'eliminar' cliente.id %} " role="button">B</a>
</td>
```

**urls.py**

```
>  urlpatterns = [
>     path('',views.inicio,name='inicio'),
>     path('nosotros',views.nosotros,name='nosotros'),
>     path('clientes',views.clientes,name='clientes'),
>     path('clientes/crear',views.crear,name='crear'),
>     path('clientes/editar',views.editar,name='editar'),
>     path('eliminar/<int:id>',views.eliminar,name='eliminar'),
>     path('clientes/editar/<int:id>',views.editar,name='editar'),
>     ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are many url path with the same name and same view, you cannot do that:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.inicio,name='inicio'),
    path('nosotros',views.nosotros,name='nosotros'),
    path('clientes',views.clientes,name='clientes'),
    path('clientes/crear',views.crear,name='crear'),
#    path('clientes/editar',views.editar,name='editar'),
    path('eliminar/<int:id>',views.eliminar,name='eliminar'),
    path('clientes/editar/<int:id>',views.editar,name='editar'),
]
```